# Does [:] slice only make shallow copy of a list?

Tags: python, numpy

I have experienced peculiar bugs from this `[:]` copy.

[The docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) say `[:]` makes only  a shallow copy but seems:

```
a = [1,2,3]
id(a)
3071203276L
b=a[:]
id(b)
3071234156L
```

`id(a)` is not equal to `id(b)`; how is that only a shallow copy?

Peculiar case:

```
import numpy as np
import random
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b=a[:]
random.shuffle(a)
```

`b` changes correspondingly.

Comment: The ids for a and b are different as one would expect for a copy. What's the problem?

Comment: its a shallow copy because deep copies are expensive - and frequently not desirable.

Comment: Slice is a shallow copy. But whether shallow or deep, the top level object will always be a copy.

Comment: See below: `id()` cannot distinguish deep vs. shallow copies. Only copy vs. non-copy (`b=a; print id(a), id(b)`).

Comment: Numpy makes this a different question. Numpy slices means you are just copying the *index*, not the backing storage. You can even change the shape of an array this way. They are designed to look like python lists, but they aren't.

Comment: Read this http://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/advanced_numpy/#life-of-ndarray

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a shallow copy, but changing `b` does not affect `a` in this case because the elements are just numbers. If they were references then `a` would be updated:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a[:]

b[1] = 5
print "a: ", a
print "b: ", b
# a: [1, 2, 3]
# b: [1, 5, 3]
```

vs

```
a = [[1], [2], [3]]
b = a[:]

b[1][0] = 5
print "a: ", a
print "b: ", b
# a:  [[1], [5], [3]]
# b:  [[1], [5], [3]]
```

Comment: does it explain the case of numpy array in updated thread? thx

Comment: I don't know enough about numpy to correctly answer that case.

Answer (score 7):

Numpy answer:

Arrays in numpy are *views/indexes on a backing storage*.

You can *copy* the view, without copying the backing storage...

```
a=numpy.array([1,2,3,4])
b=a[:] # copy of the array ("view" or "index"), not the storage
b.shape=(2,2)
print a
# [1 2 3 4]
print b
# [[1 2]
#  [3 4]]
b *= 2
print a
# [2 4 6 8]
print b
# [[2 4]
#  [6 8]]
```

See how changing b affected a? Yet they still have a different shape. Consider them to be *views of the data*; and the `b=a[:]` line copied just this view. I could even modify the shape of `b`. Because it is just an index to the data, that says where columns and rows are located in memory.

If you want a copy of the backing storage in numpy, use `a.copy()`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the only thing that makes a deep copy is `deepcopy`.

Because deep copies are expensive, as you need to track every object you copied.

Consider evil structures like this:

```
a = []
a.append(a)
```

You certainly won't want to make a naive deep copy of this.

So yes, it is a shallow copy. But in your example, it is storing primitives, which will be copied as value, not as reference. So modifying one list won't modify the other.

**`id()` cannot be used to distinguish shallow and deep copies**

It distinguishes copies from non-copies (which have the same id).

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a
print id(b), id(a), "no surprise, same id, no copy."
```

**Numpy arrays are different**

Here, you only "shallow copy" the index, not the data which is in a backing storage. Use `.copy()` if you want to make sure you have a copy.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that the elements of list a and list b are the same. Changing mutable objects in either list also effects the elements in the other list.

In contrast there is deepcopy which tries to create a completely different set of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy defines what what a slice returns differently to the standard python library. This is because numpy is made to work with huge amounts of data. Copying these huge arrays is not always wanted, especially if the user only wanted a temporary view of the array. For instance,  `arr[:100].sum()` sums the first 100 elements, without having to create a temporary shallow copy of the first 100 elements. Note that temporary views are only created for a *basic* slice.

See the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) for more details.