# List being reassigned new values when not explicitly told to do so

Tags: python, macos, list

I am writing a program that dose many math computations that eventually make a list of points to plot.  I does so over several iterations and gets one point per iteration, and then uses the new point for the next iteration in the code.  The list `conditions_old` holds the values from the last iteration.  The list `conditions_new` are the new points that are found after an iteration is finished.  At the end of the code, the lists are set equal to each other: `conditions_old = conditions_new`.  This is the only time `conditions_old` is assigned a value except for the initial conditions that are used to start the calculations.  With all that said, here is the problem I'm having:

```
conditions_old = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

kCompute = conditions_old[:]

for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        print("conditions_old BEFORE: ", conditions_old[i][j])
        kCompute[i][j] = (conditions_old[i][j] + (1/4))  # This is where things get fishy.
        print("conditions_old AFTER: ", conditions_old[i][j])
        print("kCompute: ", kCompute[i][j])
```

This is a small portion of my code.  What happens is that the list `conditions_old` will acquire the values of `kCompute` once that calculation has been made.  My question is this; why is `conditions_old` acquiring the the new value of `kCompute`?  Also, how do you fix this problem?

I've  seen python do some odd things before, but this is something I never expected to run into.

I'm currently using python 3.4 on Yosemite

Comment: [Other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27629727/does-slice-only-make-shallow-copy-of-a-list) [possibilities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068707/slicing-operation-give-deep-copy-or-shallow-copy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that:

```
kCompute = conditions_old[:]
```

makes a **shallow** copy.  In your line:

```
kCompute[i][j] = (conditions_old[i][j] + (1/4))  # This is where things get fishy.
```

You're setting the value on one of the inner lists which is shared with `conditions_old` due to the shallow nature of your copy.  In other words:

```
kCompute is conditions_old  # False
kCompute[0] is conditions_old[0]  # True
```

The easiest fix is to do a [deep copy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy):

```
from copy import deepcopy

...
kCompute = copy.deepcopy(conditions_old)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a deep copy of the original list before it has been edited.

`kCompute = conditions_old[:]` only makes a shallow copy, this the lists within the two lists, reference the same objects.

You can make a deep copy to avoid this issue:

```
from copy import deepcopy
kCompute = deepcopy(conditions_old)
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html):

A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in the original.

A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.