# Python - not sure why two lists are looking the same (one is being updated in the function)

Tags: python, list, numpy, reference, scikit-learn

I created a list of lists(each row has 784 elements) - this is image data 28x28 matrix

```
train_data, train_labels = X[:60000], Y[:60000]
```

For blurring the images - here are two functions that calculate a new value of each pixel - average based on 8 neighboring elements in the 28x28 matrix (ignored first/last row and first/last column for simplicity i.e. loop from 2-26 instead of 0-27)

```
def new_func(x_train_data,train_data):
    for index in range(x_train_data.shape[0]):
        imgvector = x_train_data[index].reshape(28, 28)
        for iblur in range(2, 27):
            for jblur in range(2, 27):
                imgvector[iblur][jblur] = getNewVaueofPixel(imgvector, iblur, jblur)
        print "blurring complete"
        x_train_data[index] = imgvector.reshape(1, 784)
        print np.array_equal(x_train_data[index], train_data)

def getNewVaueofPixel(imgvector, iblur, jblur):
    pixelval = 0.0  
    for ib in range(-1, 2):
        for jb in range(-1, 2):
            pixelval = pixelval + imgvector[iblur + ib][jblur + jb]
    outval = round(pixelval / 8.0, 12)
    return ('{:.12f}'.format(outval)).rstrip('0') or 0.
```

Here's the function call:

```
x_train_data = train_data[:1]
x_train_labels = train_labels[0]
new_func(x_train_data,train_data[0])
```

Below line in the function returns true, but when i look at the value of x_train_data[index], it is not the same as original and has been updated correctly.

```
print np.array_equal(x_train_data[index], train_data)
```

I've spent more than 12hrs debugging this but not getting anywhere. Just can't understand why train_data is getting updated when

```
x_train_data = train_data[:1]
```

should create a copy of the list and not a reference to it. Appreciate any help.

Comment: If `train_data` is a `numpy.array`, rather than a list (of lists), `[:1]` creates a `view`, not a copy.  You may need to read up on basic numpy arrays (New `sckit-learn` users seem to jump in without knowing much about `numpy`, even though the kit is built on that package.).  Within in your function `x_train_data` has a `shape` attribute, as sure indicator that it is an array, not a list.

Comment: Even in normal python, using [:1] would create [a shallow copy](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/copy.html). That is, _"A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in the original."_

Comment: thanks @Fermiparadox and @hpaulj! I think I need to setup a new array of zeros and update the values in it. Will read up on numpy.arrarys.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/glossary.html#term-view

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/27629902/3374996

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does \[:\] slice only make shallow copy of a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27629727/does-slice-only-make-shallow-copy-of-a-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `x_train_data = train_data[:1]` creates a [view](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/glossary.html#term-view) in numpy, as [@hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj) said.

For example:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(5)
y = x[:3]

print(x)    # [0 1 2 3 4]
print(y)    # [0 1 2]

y[0] = 14   # This changes x as well

print(x)    # [14  1  2  3  4]
print(y)    # [14  1  2]
```

---

Also, in normal python it would create a [shallow copy](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/copy.html).

```
x = [1, [2, 3]]

y = x[:]

print(x)    # [1, [2, 3]]
print(y)    # [1, [2, 3]]

y[1].append(7)   # changes x as well

print(x)   # [1, [2, 3, 7]]
print(y)   # [1, [2, 3, 7]]
```